# Why does Google Play Store show installed apps in the "Previously installed apps" section?

Tags: google-play-store

When I go to the *Previously installed apps* section of Google Play Store, some apps that are currently installed on my phone are also shown. I thought that may be all of the currently installed apps shown were not updated, but that not the case for some of them.

Should it not be only apps that were removed or not installed that should appear?

I have checked the issue with phones using Android 6.0.1 & 8.1. As you can see on the image below, VLC is installed, yet it is listed on previously installed apps.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I don't have that section at all, there's only `Installed` and `Library` which are self explanatory.

Comment: Check the picture from the edit

Comment: Well any app on your device and any app that was once on your device both classify as "previously installed", otherwise how else would they be there in the first place?

Comment: It might be semantics, but I expect to only see apps that are not installed on that section. I already know the apps that are installed on the phone

Comment: Sure, but the line "give one a go" probably suggests that the app has been downloaded but rarely/never used. I don't see any issue here.

Comment: I use VLC on a daily basis, and yet it is listed

Comment: you may need to scroll down to find that section, @trishmapow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I surmise that because you can have multiple devices with the same account. It puts apps that were installed on a device in that section, regardless of them being installed on the current device or not. Though I do not see why they could not filter out apps that are installed on the device.

I would suggest that if you think it is an issue, you can report it using the feedback. Aside from that action, I do not think there is anything that could be done on the user side to fix this.

Comment: Your explanation seems probable +1